# Computer freezes after login screen

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, login, login-screen

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 lts. My computer suddenly kicked me to login screen while I was playing Half-Life 2.

After that I entered my password and tried to login as normal... the login box dissapeared... and all I could see was the background picture (of the login screen;not my desktop wallpaper).

Same thing happens everytime I try to login wıth my account (same problem when I tried from guest account). I can only move the mouse.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reinstalling KDE from the tty would help, but I'm not sure about this. You would have to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to leave your desktop (tty7) and enter a plain full-screen terminal (tty1). This should allow you to login by entering your username and pw. Then you can try running `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop --reinstall`. After that, Ctrl+Alt+F7 will bring you back to your GUI/desktop.

Comment: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amarok-utils amd64 2:2.8.0-0ubuntu3

Comment: Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'...(continues) thats what I got when I tried it. Thanks for the answer. Maybe my repositories are all messed up... Something to do with amarok. When I try sudo apt-get update I get some similar results. Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg     Could not resolve...

Comment: That sounds weird. What about running apt-get with "-f" or "dist-upgrade"? This should try repairing something, but possibly not what you mentioned, it would not hurt anyway.

Comment: Tried no luck. Also tried autoremove. Didn't do the trick still stuck after login. Might have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: I polished your question a bit and included what we found out together. Just be patient until someone comes with an idea...